# PyGame Queueing Music Problems, not waiting for first song

Tags: python, pygame, queueing

I'm playing ogg sound files from a list generated from my selected music file directory. For some reason the first song is skipped and it plays starting from the second song. For some reason it plays a split second of the first song occasionally which leads me to believe there's an issue on how I'm trying to queue the songs from a list in a loop but I can't seem to fix it.

```
import pygame
import sys
import os
from pygame.locals import * 
surface = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
musicDir = "/Users/user/Desktop/Dat Sound/Music/"
x = os.listdir(musicDir)
del(x[0]) # Deleting first element because it's DS Store file (Mac)
print x # The list is ['Bonfire.ogg', 'Voodoo Child.ogg']
n = ''
count = 1
pygame.mixer.init()
for i in range(len(x)):
    n = musicDir + str(x[i])
    print n  
    pygame.mixer.music.load(n)
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
    pygame.mixer.music.queue(musicDir + str(x[i]))
    # I'm queueing the next song in the list of songs from the folder + its location
    print pygame.mixer.music.get_busy() 
    # get_busy returns true for both files but only the second is playing
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
          running = False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're loading and playing a song, then queueing it, but then loading and playing the second song on the next iteration of the loop, then queueing it again...

```
n = musicDir + str(x[i])
pygame.mixer.music.load(n) # so you load the song...
pygame.mixer.music.play()  # then you play it....
pygame.mixer.music.queue(musicDir + str(x[i])) # i hasn't changed, this is the same song 
                                               #  you just loaded and started playing
```

Then the `for` loops goes to the next iteration and you do *the exact same thing*, but with the next song.

Try something like this:

```
n = musicDir + str[0]   # let's load and play the first song
pygame.mixer.music.load(n)
pygame.mixer.music.play()
for song in x: 
    pygame.mixer.music.queue(musicDir + str(song)) # loop over and queue the rest
```